# Can I make sql server management studio not require [] around table names?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

If I copy and paste a query into sql management studio to debug it, I have to change all the table names from tableName to [database].[dbo].[tableName], Can this be avoided?

Comment: Are you talking about Management Studio?

Comment: I am sorry, edited.

Comment: SSMS doesn't *require* the square quotes, in any version of SQL Server. Have you tried something that failed?

Comment: Well at the very least it requires the database and schema name. I had hoped there was a setting that would let me select default ones if I don't specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also matters which database you are using. When you open a default query window, it selects Master as your database. You can either manually change it to your database, which will just accept table names after that or you can specify in your query with a 
    Use Databasename;

Otherwise, you will need to specify the databasename.schema.table name with every reference. This is also how you can query across multiple databases in the same query window.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is called QuoteName and is required when you don't have a [valid identifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) for an object..

**For Example**

this fails

```
create table dbo.123
       (
       id  int
       )
```

this succeeds

```
  create table dbo.[123]
       (
       id  int
       )
```

So in summary,`[]` isnot necessary,if you have a valid identifier and is required when you dont have one